# having troubles wiht python syntax especially on a if check

Tags: python, syntax

```
 for i in range(len(nestedlist)):
     if nestedlist[i][-1]=!0:
         print(str(nestedlist)[i][0])+" "+str(nestedlist)[i][-1]))
```

This code works, the if is the thing that ruins this can some one help?

Comment: If you wish to do some more research into operators, you can read up here. `https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-operator/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=!` is not a valid operator You need to update `=!` to `!=`

```
test = 1
test1 = 2
test =! test1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
test != test1
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The inequality syntax is wrong, it should be `!=` rather than `=!`